# Python zeromq not successfully sending messages (netstat -anf -inet lists it as LISTEN)

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, zeromq

I have the following code:

```
import zmq
import time

context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket.bind("tcp://*:5555")

while True:
    time.sleep (1)
    socket.send("Hello, World")
```

for some reason it does not seem to be correctly sending the message; when i run

```
'netstat -anf inet'
```

in bash, it returns the following:

```
 Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)    
 ...
 tcp4       0      0  *.5555                 *.*                    LISTEN 
 ...
```

From googling around, it looks like "LISTEN" all the way on the right means that it's not actually binding correctly. (This entire line goes away when i shut down the python script mentioned above, and there is no other mention of 5555.) Any ideas what is going wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Could you show the code of subscriber? It seems that there's nothing wrong with the publisher code.

Comment: The **LISTEN** state means `The socket is listening for incoming connections` from the `netstat` manual page.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no network traffic if you have no connected SUB sockets with active subscriptions. Subscriptions are filtered PUB-side, so if there are no active subscribers for a message when you call `send`, it just discards the message. You should see network traffic if you add a subscriber:

```
sub = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
sub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
sub.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
```